# CSS file is not being loaded in MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am unable to access CSS file which is located under MVC AREA section.

Here is the full path of the CSS file.

http://mywebsite/Areas/MVC/Resources/dist/css/custom.css

The path is correct I suppose because JS files and images are being loaded from the same path.

There is also no authentication issue as well.

I tried to debug using firebug and it prints the following error message.

The stylesheet http://mywebsite/Areas/MVC/Resources/dist/css/custom.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".
Although I have specified the text/css type in the link attribute.

I am referring to the css file as below

link href="~/Areas/MVC/Resources/dist/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"

I have also tried giving the absolute path but still no luck.

If we try to open the above link in browser it is opening correctly and showing CSS but it does not load in the application. Also the js resources and images are being loaded in the same folder by using the same path but not the CSS.

Comment: Can you post (some of - maybe just the top 20 lines or so, if it's a big file) your CSS? Your error is suggesting that the code in it might not be formatted correctly as a .css file

Comment: that error sounds like your server is sending it across as text

Comment: are you using some kind of handler to serve your css?

Comment: @GeoffJames I am loading a bootstap file and it is not being loaded as well. In short no css file is working

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama no I am not using any handler

Comment: @Asim Are you serving your Bootstrap css locally, or from a CDN?

Comment: @GeoffJames locally. All external css files and CDN files are working fine. For the temporary solution I have hosted my css files on google drive and refered from there.

Comment: @Asim Then, as long as you're declaring your `<link rel...>`s in your head (as suggestted by @Troy) it seems like there is a problem with your local css files. Could you please post some screenshots/sample code of your css, as previously requested?

Comment: @GeoffJames  here is the file.

http://bilalhussain.website/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: @Asim Then, *again*, can you please include some code in your OP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115506/discussion-between-asim-and-geoff-james).

Comment: the problem is with the server not how it's linked in the file... google drive is not serving it with the proper content-type header, that's your problem

Comment: you need to put it somewhere else where it will be served with the correct content-type header

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama I have put it on my own hosting and it is working fine.  I have figured out the issue but looking for solution. My css files is rendered as html page. I open the link directly and it is HTML page with text in it but when I open file from other CDN source and save the file It is .css extension file

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. But what you describe (especially with reference to google drive) is an issue with the `Content-Type` HTTP header sent from the server that serves the css file

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama any solution then ?

Comment: sorry I don't understand the question; the solution is to get the server to send the right `Content-Type` header... most web servers do this automagically

Answer (score 0):

As Geoff stated if you could provide a screenshot or a snippet of code along with the error we could give you a more detailed answer.

the only thing I can think of is using the rel attribute and telling your app it's a stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```

Like above for example. Just to clarify this should be placed in the head of your index.html

Comment: this is the link I am using to refer my CSS files. href="~/Areas/MVC/Resources/dist/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"

Comment: Are you sure you have you the right path to your file? Navigate to you're desired css file via the terminal then type 'pwd' this will show your path to the file you have just navigated too then use that path in your index.html.

Comment: Yes I am sure I have navigate the path return by firebug and my Css code was there. The js files are running from same folder using same path